# Node JS Javascript Class TypeError is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I cannot understand why my code is not working. I have a basic class with two class methods. I am trying to access the second class method from within the first and am getting a type error saying the second method is not a function. LOL I do this all the time, what am I missing?

```
import models from '../../db';

class GroupRoleCheck {

  constructor() {
    this.group = null;
  }

  isGroupAdmin(params, callback) {
    let groupId = params.groupId;
    let userId = params.user.id;

    models.Group.findById(groupId, {
      include: [{ all: true }]
    })
    .then(group => {
      this.group = group;

      let found = this.group.Users.find(user => {
        return userId === user.id;
      });

      if (found) {
        return found.GroupMembers;
      }
    })
    .then(members => {

      if (members.role === 'groupAdmin') {
        return callback(null, true);
      } else {

        this.isOrgSuper();

        return callback({
          message: 'not authorized'
        }, false)
      }
    })
  }

  isOrgSuper() {
    console.log('===================================');
    console.log(this.group);
    console.log('===================================');
  }
}

export default GroupRoleCheck;
```

[image]

[image]

Update:

I am calling this from another file where I am implementing RBAC2 and passing the call rbac.

```
import RBAC from 'rbac2';

import UserRoleCheck from '../permissions/user.permission';
import OrgRoleCheck from '../permissions/org.permission';
import GroupRoleCheck from '../permissions/group.permission';

let userRoleCheck = new UserRoleCheck();
let orgRoleCheck = new OrgRoleCheck();
let groupRoleCheck = new GroupRoleCheck();

let rules = [
  // Users:
  {
    a: 'admin',
    can: 'view organizations',
    when: userRoleCheck.isOrgAdminAll
  },
  // Organizations:
  {
    a: 'admin',
    can: 'view org details',
    when: orgRoleCheck.isOrgAdmin
  },
  {
    a: 'super',
    can: 'edit org details',
    when: orgRoleCheck.isOrgSuper
  },
  {
    a: 'super',
    can: 'delete org',
    when: orgRoleCheck.isOrgSuper
  },
  // Groups:
  {
    a: 'admin',
    can: 'create group',
    when: orgRoleCheck.isOrgAdmin
  },
  {
    a: 'admin',
    can: 'view group details',
    when: groupRoleCheck.isGroupAdmin
  },
  {
    a: 'super',
    can: 'edit group details',
    when: orgRoleCheck.isOrgSuper
  },
  {
    a: 'super',
    can: 'delete group',
    when: orgRoleCheck.isOrgSuper
  }
];

let rbac = new RBAC(rules);
export default rbac;
```

Comment: How are you calling this from another component?

Comment: the context for this might be getting set to something else depending on how you're calling this.

Comment: I updated the post to show where the call is coming from. I am passing those calls into RBAC via an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a context problem, by passing your `isGroupAdmin` function by ref you lose track of the instance. I presume RBAC internally will be invoking the function via `call` or `apply`.

Simple fix is to update your rules in such a way that `when` invokes the function on the instance e.g. `when: (params, cb) => orgRoleCheck.isGroupAdmin(params, cb)`

Comment: @Aaron one thing to consider is do these classes need to be instances? I see you manage some sort of state in there (`this.group`) however it's worth determining if that is really needed. That would allow you to switch to a completely stateless model and your code would work the way you would like (of course with some small modifictions).

Comment: I stored the group state because I plan on using it in the isOrgSuper method. I need to determine if the user is a super admin if the group admin check is false, which requires getting the associated organization and check the org role against the userId. I figured do that rather than make another call to the db to get the same group. I bet there are much better ways to do this. I am by occupation a frontend dev with angular and react and I wanted to begin learning backend. This application is my first pass at both front and backend. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Im guessing your suggesting to turn the classes into simple function exports ?

Comment: @Aaron well the most obvious change would be to just pass it as a parameter to `isOrgSuper` rather than calling it and relying on internal state, given you have it at that point. You could do a check for it i.e. `if (!params.group) { // lookup group }`

Comment: @Aaron not even that, you can still keep the class but just convert the functions to be truly static e.g. `static isOrgSuper() { ... }` etc.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you.